# AWS RDS Aborted Connection Haproxy

Tags: mysql, mariadb, haproxy, amazon-rds

I create 1 master and 2 replication in AWS RDS and 1 EC2 with haproxy

```
listen rds-cluster
    bind 172.30.0.xxx:3306
    mode tcp
    option mysql-check user ha_check
    balance roundrobin
    server mysql-1 replica1.xxxx.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 check weight 1 fall 2 fastinter 1000
    server mysql-2 replica2.xxxx.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 check weight 1 fall 2 fastinter 1000
```

If I can connect directly using endpoint to replica server,
But if I using haproxy

```
$ mysql -h172.30.0.xxx -uha_read -ppassword -e "show variables like 'server_id'"
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

i got that error

I already increase connect_timeout

if I check

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Aborted_connects';
```

it's keep increasing

===============

This article solve my problem
[CUSTOM CONFIGURATION OF AMAZON RDS INSTANCES](http://www.microbasecloud.com/?p=408)

Comment: silly questions first :) did you enable communication to your RDS from haproxy, e.g from a Security group point of view?

Comment: First I just follow this tutorial http://www.tothenew.com/blog/load-blancing-of-amazon-rds-read-replica/ , do you have any sample todo with that? thanks

Comment: allow all traffic in bound and out bound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default if you did not change the security group settings when launch RDS, only your IP will be authorized to reach your databases. In your case you need to authorize your haproxy node to reach your databases as well.

Go to RDS, select your instance, then security group, edit, add a new rule to enable either the security group of your HAproxy (best practice) or HAproxy IP (still good enough if this is an elastic IP) to access the database on port 3306.

Hope this is clear enough :)

EDIT: I understand that you solved your issue, but for people reading later (or even for you if you want to enhance security) I add a little information about what I said: 
the RDS hostname will be resolved to private IP when the DNS query is made from an instance in the same VPC to the Amazon provided DNS server in that VPC. Thus in your security group, in that case, you would have to allow either the subnet of you haproxy or its private IP (not public one).

Comment: Thanks, I already change it to accept all traffic, the problem is in parameter group

Comment: Thanks Tom, Appreciate it ( but I can't vote up, need more karma ) . I change to allow all trafic because of i have an issue. But know i will re-configure my security group setting.